# Using font-face definition received via API as a string in frontend

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am getting custom font via API as a String given below,

```
"@font-face {
  font - family: 'Custom Font Name';
  src: url('https://base_url/fonts/pGdyQlal_QW0WERKk_405638ad.eot');
  src: url('https://base_url/fonts/pGdyQlal_QW0WERKk_405638ad.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('https://base_url/fonts/pGdyQlal_QW0WERKk_405638ad.ttf') format('opentype'),
  url('https://base_url/fonts/pGdyQlal_QW0WERKk_405638ad.woff') format('woff');
  font - weight: normal;
  font - style: normal;
}
"
```

I need to put this font-family definition in style tag of a php/html file or write/append in an existing CSS file so that I can use the Custom Font Name as a value for font-family property.
I have to populate select dropdown for selecting these custom fonts received in API.
I am using Javascript, jQuery for Scripting.

Please guide for the way out, as what is getting received is a string and not getting recognised as css.

Comment: Please show some code you've already tried and describe how it didnt work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stylesheet Injection?

This ought to do it. Creating a stylesheet and setting its innerHTML to your CSS String. Enjoy!

```
function injectCSS( str ) {
    const style = document.createElement( 'style' );
    style.innerHTML = str;
    document.body.appendChild( style );
}

injectCSS( cssStr );

const cssStr = `@font-face {
  font - family: 'Custom Font Name';
  src: url('https://base_url/fonts/pGdyQlal_QW0WERKk_405638ad.eot');
  src: url('https://base_url/fonts/pGdyQlal_QW0WERKk_405638ad.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('https://base_url/fonts/pGdyQlal_QW0WERKk_405638ad.ttf') format('opentype'),
  url('https://base_url/fonts/pGdyQlal_QW0WERKk_405638ad.woff') format('woff');
  font - weight: normal;
  font - style: normal;
}`;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to. Please check the documentation of your webfont provider. You will find a script which when put in side your html makes the font automatically available to your page.